# How to initialize recaptcha in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I used the following guide: http://www.tweetegy.com/2012/10/setting-up-a-captcha-with-recaptcha-service-and-the-captcha-gem/

I have the following in development.rb:

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'keyString'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = 'keyString'
```

In config/initializers/recaptcha.rb:

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
  config.private_key = RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY
end
```

I get the following error when I run rails server in development:

```
Exiting                                                                                                                                           
/home/action/visualhaggard.org/config/initializers/recaptcha.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY (Nam
eError)
```

Has anyone encountered and solved this problem?  Do I have a typo?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example doesn't define the RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY in an environment variable. It just defines it as a constant.

```
#put this in development.rb and in production.rb (separate keys in each so you can test!)
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY= 'your-public-key'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY= 'your-private-key'
```